# Parsing CSV using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Is there a way the top row of the csv can be used to make column headers for the elasticsearch index? As in my csv, columns are not fixed in numbers or names.

Also the requirement is to convert all the datatypes based on a regex to integer/float. Can mutate do that?

Comment: I am using autogenerate_column_names => false but is still does not consider first row as the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Embulk tools 'guess' command option. This command will interpret the data and automatically assign format to it.

Look at 'Loading a csv file' section in this link,

http://www.embulk.org/docs/recipe/scheduled-csv-load-to-elasticsearch-kibana4.html

Comment: link is expired can you provide a valid link, thank you